# Where I can find Kubernetes PV on the host filesystem?

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I am trying to understand how Kubernetes handles the persistent volumes on the node's filesystem.

For example, if I have a minikube as my Kubernetes cluster node, and I create multiple PVs with PVC for may pods and if I ssh to minikube, where I can find the PV on minikube's filesystem?

If I type

> lsblk

I get

> sda      8:0    0  19.5G  0 disk

but no PV disks are listed.

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will not see it because it's inside API as an API Object.

I recommend reading Kubernetes documentation regarding [Persistent Volumes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/).

> A  `PersistentVolume`  (PV) is a piece of storage in the cluster that has been provisioned by an administrator. It is a resource in the cluster just like a node is a cluster resource. PVs are volume plugins like Volumes, but have a lifecycle independent of any individual pod that uses the PV. This API object captures the details of the implementation of the storage, be that NFS, iSCSI, or a cloud-provider-specific storage system.
>
> A  `PersistentVolumeClaim`  (PVC) is a request for storage by a user. It is similar to a pod. Pods consume node resources and PVCs consume PV resources. Pods can request specific levels of resources (CPU and Memory). Claims can request specific size and access modes (e.g., can be mounted once read/write or many times read-only).
>
> While  `PersistentVolumeClaims`  allow a user to consume abstract storage resources, it is common that users need  `PersistentVolumes`  with varying properties, such as performance, for different problems. Cluster administrators need to be able to offer a variety of  `PersistentVolumes`  that differ in more ways than just size and access modes, without exposing users to the details of how those volumes are implemented. For these needs there is the  `StorageClass`  resource.
>
> Please see the  [detailed walkthrough with working examples](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-persistent-volume-storage/).

You can also have a look at the [Kubernetes Volumes Guide](https://matthewpalmer.net/kubernetes-app-developer/articles/kubernetes-volumes-example-nfs-persistent-volume.html) which explains the types of storage, how long do they last and how to use them in examples.

Comment: Does that mean that there is no data regarding the k8s pvc on the node file system?

Comment: @brankoterzic node is just a resource like PV, both are objects in API.

Answer (score 1):

Because they are `hostPath`, you will not see them in `lsblk`. Use "kubectl describe pv PV_NAME" to understand where they are located.

Comment: I wanted to find out where PVs are located on the k8s NODE file system, and how this pv "data structure" looks like within the NODE's file system.